# Cannot overwrite variable false because it is read-only or constant

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Here is my code where I have included relevant parts:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $somepath -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Step $_.FullName
}

function Step {
    Param([string]$subfolder)

    $folders = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $subfolder -Directory -ErrorVariable $HasError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($HasError) {
        Write-Host $_.FullName "|" $HasError.Message
        return
    } else {
        $hasError, $inactive = FolderInactive $_.FullName
        if ($hasError) {
            #do nothing
        } else {
            if ($inactive) {
                SetFolderItemsReadOnly $_.FullName
            }
        }
    }

    if ($folders) {
        $folders | ForEach-Object {
            Step $_.FullName
        }
    }
}

function SetFolderItemsReadOnly {
    Param([string]$Path)

    $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -File -ErrorAction Stop

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        try {
            Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
        } catch {
            Write-Host $file.FullName " | " $_.Exception.Message
        }       
    }
}
```

I get some errors with `Set-ItemProperty` in the `SetFolderItemsReadOnly` function, that is

> Exception setting "IsReadOnly": "Access to the path is denied."

which is due to some security permissions. However after printing this error in the terminal I also get a huge red error like so:

```
Cannot overwrite variable false because it is read-only or constant.
At pathtoscript:55 char:5
+     $folders = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $subfolder  -Directory -ErrorVariable  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (false:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: did you tried running your script as administrator?

Comment: I would get that your $HasError variable is initialized to true and evaluated during your Get-ChildItem call. Try to remove the "$" in front of the name in your -ErrorVariable call.

Comment: @MartinBrandl I have. Some files aren't evenly writable even by our administrators, I don't know why. But then it should only print the "Exception setting "IsReadOnly" etc.", but sometimes it also does that weird error.

Comment: @DavidBrabant My man! That did it! The error is gone!

Comment: Not enough coffee this morning. "I would GUESS that your $HasError variable is initialized to FALSE, etc."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@DavidBrabant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633136/cannot-overwrite-variable-false-because-it-is-read-only-or-constant#comment66571145_39633136) pointed out, the parameter `-ErrorVariable` expects just the name of the variable, without the leading `$`. Also, the purpose of this variable is not to be a boolean indicator whether or not an error occured (PowerShell already provides this information via the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$?`), but to receive the actual error object.

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx):

> ```
> -ErrorVariable [+]<variable-name>
> ```
>
> Alias: `ev`
>
> Stores error messages about the command in the specified variable and in the `$Error` automatic variable. For more information, type the following command:
>
> ```
> get-help about_Automatic_Variables
> ```
>
> By default, new error messages overwrite error messages that are already stored in the variable. To append the error message to the variable content, type  a plus sign (+) before the variable name.
>
> For example, the following command creates the `$a` variable and then stores any errors in it:
>
> ```
> Get-Process -Id 6 -ErrorVariable a
> ```
>
> The following command adds any error messages to the `$a` variable:
>
> ```
> Get-Process -Id 2 -ErrorVariable +a
> ```